# r studio, how to count the number of occurrences in a list by using a for loop?

Tags: r, list

I have tried to count the number of occurrences in *window_list*, but the code doesn't work properly (only gives 0's back). What I exactly want to count is surrounded by 3 asterisk in the below mentioned *window_list*. Can anyone please help me?

```
window <- c(5, 10, 20, 35, 50)
list_output <- list()

for (i in window) {
  list_output[[paste0("window_",i)]] <- count(as.data.frame(lengths(window_list$window_i)))
}
```

This is the output when using this code:

```
list_output 
$window_5
  n
1 0
$window_10
  n
1 0
$window_20
  n
1 0

$window_35
  n
1 0
$window_50
  n
1 0
```

The window_list is looking like this:

```
$window_5
***[[1]]***
[[1]][[1]]
*several elements*
[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]]
*several elements

***[[2]]***
[[2]][[1]] 
*several elements*
[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]]
*several elements*

...............................

***[[71]]***
[[71]][[1]] 
*several elements*
[[71]][[2]]
[[71]][[2]]
*several elements*

$window_10
***[[1]]***
[[1]][[1]]
*several elements*
[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]]
*several elements

***[[2]]***
[[2]][[1]] 
*several elements*
[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]]
*several elements*

...............................

***[[76]]***
[[76]][[1]] 
*several elements*
[[76]][[2]]
[[76]][[2]]
*several elements*
```

The expected output:

```
list_output 
$window_5
 n
1 71
$window_10
 n
1 76
$window_20
 n
1 73

$window_35
 n
1 77
$window_50
 n
1 78
```

```
lengths(window_list$window_5) 
 [1] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
[65] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7

count(as.data.frame(lengths(window_list$window_i)))
   n
1 71
```

Comment: What is `window_list` ? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I think I have incorporated your feedback in the answer.

Comment: No we still don't have an actual example to test our answers with. What does `lengths(window_list)` return?

Comment: You just gave me the answer.  this code (lengths(window_list)) gives the answer! But i still want to know how it works in a for loop, so i adjusted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` is not the correct function to use here. You can try with `length` if you want to use a loop.

```
result <- integer(length(window_list))

for (i in seq_along(window_list)) {
  result[i] <- length(window_list[[i]])
}
```

However, as already mentioned using `lengths` works directly.

```
result <- lengths(window_list)
```